# c# winforms: Реализация сочетания клавиш Ctrl+Z \ Команда undo

Tags: c#, winforms

Имеется приложение winforms, где расположена таблица DataGridView. Как реализовать команду Undo, чтобы пользователь мог вернуть предыдущие значения из активной ячейки?
Поиск не дал результатов. Как тут,так и на сторонних ресурсах.

Comment: При изменении ячейки сохранять ее старое значение и координаты в `Stack<T>`, при нажатии Ctrl+Z доставать оттуда значение обратно в таблицу. А вообще, если не хочется сохранять изменения ячейки при редактировании, достаточно просто нажать Escape. Не проверял, но по-моем то же самое действует для строки. И кстати, что за таблица? DataGridView?

Comment: Да вроде полно примеров Undo/Redo в тырнете. Какой именно способ выбрать, зависит от того, что используется у вас. Используется ли привязка данных? И пр.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а можно увидеть какой-либо наиболее простой? Реально не нашел ничего кроме платных фреймворков.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/259114/226545